# Tableau Reference Line that avoids the current filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I have tasks that are either completed or not.  These tasks are associated with a project that has a start and end date.  When a task is completed, it gets a completed timestamp.

I want to show a chart of a running total of completed tasks with a reference line that goes from the bottom left corner to the top right corner.  I want the slope of this line to be defined by the total number of tasks agnostic to completeness over the difference between the projects start and end date.

I have successfully created a reference line whose slope is defined by the total number of completed tasks over the timespan of the filtered data.  In other words, my problem is that I can't get the reference line to be omitted from the current filter.

Here is a picture of what I'm looking for:
[image]
Imagine that that blue line was straight.  The read line is my running total of task completions with their task completion timestamps deciding their position along the x axis.  I want a straight line that shows what the rate of progress would be for the whole entirety of the project assuming that tasks were completed at a constant rate.

### Update

I've tried to create the line via two points as a second data source in the form of a custom sql script:

```
SELECT p.ProjectId, n * COUNT(t.TaskListId) AS Tasks, IIF(n = 0, p.DateStart, p.DateEnd) AS DATE
FROM (VALUES (0),(1)) v(n)
INNER JOIN analysis.Tasks t ON t.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
INNER JOIN analysis.FacilityProject p ON t.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
GROUP BY v.n, p.ProjectId, p.DateStart, p.DateEnd
ORDER BY ProjectId, Tasks
```

When I add this to my worksheet, it slows Tableau Desktop to a crawl.  I'm not sure what to do, because it splits the columns from this query into dimensions and measures (`Date` appears in Dimensions > Task Counts and `Tasks` appears in Measures > Task Counts).  I've tried putting `Tasks` in both Rows and Columns and it seems to really tick off Tableau Desktop.

The following calculated field does not work.  I'm attempting to understand the existing answer below, but I'm attempting arithmetic with a mixture of aggregated and non-aggregated values.  Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Level of Detail expressions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) will allow you to "fix" your calculation to a specific dimension.  Moreover, LoD expressions are calculated BEFORE Dimension or Measure filters.

You can use the FIXED keyword, along with the dimension on which the calculation should be based.  So, if the least specific dimension you have is Date (i.e.  It's the first dimension), you can do:

```
{FIXED [Date] : <aggregation calculation for line> }
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I'm looking for, absolutely!  I'm having a bit of trouble with the right side of this expression.  If I want my line to be based on a constant rate of completion (straight diagonal line from bottom left to top right), how would I do that?  It's like the Y value (completed tasks) would be the same ratio as the ratio between the time that has passed and the allotted time for the project (total).

Comment: @JakeSmith : If you just want a diagonal line that is equi-distant from the X and Y axis, at 45 degrees.  So, think of it as a slope line between two points:  (0,0) and (max X, max Y).  The "right side" of your LoD expression would be the slope formula, I think?

Comment: I know about slope and how it is defined.  I just can't get Tableau to help me define it in their syntax.  `Total Tasks / date range` is the slope.  My struggle here is I don't know what `FIXED [Date]` is doing, and when I type this division/slope equation in, it gives an error that does not indicate what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @JakeSmith : `FIXED [Date]` just means that Tableau is doing the calculation that the level of the `[Date]` dimension.  I'll see if I can work up a generic example to help explain.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Meanwhile, I generated this SQL script that I could load in as Custom SQL to have another datasource.  Can't quite get what I'm after yet, but this might also be another alternative.  I'll update my question

Comment: @JakeSmith : to get the start and end point of your line:  formula 1 `point 1 x` = <the min date for your X data>; formula 2 `point 1 y` = 0;  formula 3 `point 2 x` = <the max date for your X data>; formula 4 `point 2 y` = <the max Y value for your data>; formula 5: `plot points` = IF [Date] = [point 1 x] THEN [point 1 y] ELSEIF [Date] = [point 2 x] THEN [point 2 y] END;  Right click and drag `plot points` to rows and select the non-aggregated option (i.e.  you don't want SUM([plot points])...just [plot points].  This should give you the start and end points.

Comment: Here's an example showing the start and end points from a dataset I have:  https://www.screencast.com/t/kkGqeDSMqqTM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171353/discussion-between-jake-smith-and-devlin-carnate).